# VB.NET date array handling issues

Tags: vb.net, arrays, date

I am having a few problems trying to set up a subroutine in Visual Basic .NET to go through an array of records and remove all records where the date field is before the current date.
Here is my current code:

```
Sub FutureDate()
        Dim movefrom As Integer
        For x As Integer = 0 To UBound(notifications)

            If notifications(x).MeetingTime < Now.Date Then  'Finds first current/future date.
                movefrom = x
            End If
        Next
        Dim moveto As Integer = 0
        For x As Integer = movefrom To UBound(notifications) 'Moves dates after this to beginning of array.
            movefrom += 1
            notifications(moveto) = notifications(movefrom)
            moveto += 1
        Next
        ReDim Preserve notifications(moveto)  'Shortens the array to the correct length.
    End Sub
```

After this sub is called, the program shows the first three records in the array in message boxes (for debugging purposes). However, when I run the program, the message boxes are never displayed. This sub is definitely the problem, as commenting out the line that calls it fixes the problem, and the appropriate messages appear, albeit with the first box containing a date in the past. This is for a notifications/upcoming meetings system, so I obviously don't want to include dates that have passed.

The records are already sorted by date, so to my eyes this should do what I want it to, which is remove the records with dates in the past, move everything else to the front of the array, and then remove the spaces at the end that the records were moved from. However, I often make stupid mistakes with things like this, so outside input is much appreciated. Any help you can give would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to use linq? I think what your trying to accomplish might be more easily done using linq.

Comment: Ah thank you, I never even considered that option. That will make things much simpler.

Comment: lambda expressions are awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a one-liner:

```
Sub FutureDate()
    notifications = notifications.Where(Function(n) n.MeetingTime < Today).ToArray()
End Sub
```

But a better design is to build a function that *returns* the new array:

```
Function FutureDate(ByVal items() As MyType) As MyType()
    Return items.Where(Function(n) n.MeetingTime < Today).ToArray()
End Function
```

And even better still is to think in terms of **sequences** rather than arrays:

```
Function FutureDate(ByVal items As IEnumerable(Of MyType)) As IEnumerable(Of MyType)
    Return items.Where(Function(n) n.MeetingTime < Today)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime[] futureDates = notifications.Where(n => n.MeetingTime > DateTime.Now).Select(n => n.MeetingTime).ToArray();
```

That should work, I think. If not, it's very similar. That should return just the dates from the meetings that are later than Now.

Hope this helps.